# using curl with authentication

Tags: node.js, curl

I am running a local node.js server. I need to make a POST request with curl. It this request a user should be authenticated. So I specify user name and password in the request. The problem is that I get an error that the token cannot be found, even though login credentials are correct (I can login to the remote server directly).

```
curl  --user username:mypassword -X POST -d '["some data"]' "http://0.0.0.0:3000/problems/problemId"
```

The server responses:

```
can not find match token bXNoYXZsb4Z1
```

What can be the problem? Do I use curl correctly?

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough details about the server side in your question but the problem could come from the encoding of the POST data.

From the man page of [`curl`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=curl) :

> -d, --data is the same as  --data-ascii.  To  post  data  purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.

So you should try these different options.

The `-X` option could also be removed. From the man page :

> Normally you don't need this option. All  sorts  of  GET,  HEAD, POST and PUT requests are rather invoked by using dedicated command line options.